# Drag and drop the one div again and again to the next divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

My HTML file is

```
<div id="dragAnwr" ></div>  
            <div id="dropimg" > </div>
              <div id="dropAnswr1" class="dropbox" ></div>
              <div id="dropAnswr2" class="dropbox" ></div>
              <div id="dropAnswr3" class="dropbox" ></div>
              <div id="dropAnswr4" class="dropbox" ></div>
```

and My jQuery File is

```
$( "#dragAnwr" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid",cursor: 'move',containment: "parent", });
    $( "#dropAnswr1" ).add( "#dropAnswr2").add( "#dropAnswr3").add( "#dropAnswr3").add( "#dropAnswr4").droppable({

    drop: function( event, ui ) {

         hoverClass: "drop-hover"
      }

    });
```

here i wanna drag the  dragAnwr Div into the following Divs

```
<div id="dropAnswr1" class="dropbox" ></div>
                  <div id="dropAnswr2" class="dropbox" ></div>
                  <div id="dropAnswr3" class="dropbox" ></div>
                  <div id="dropAnswr4" class="dropbox" ></div>
```

Using my jQuery Code only the one time the dragAnwr div drop into any of other div. here i wanna drag and drop the dragAnwr div again and again to the next divs. so please give a perfect solution. Thanks

Comment: Check your HTML again. I think you have a mistaken </div>

Comment: checked please give a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you really want. But I think you want that user may change the answer after dropping the answer flag.

So here is my solution

```
// HTML
<div id="dragAnwr" >'   ' is Answer </div>
<div id="dropAnswr1" class="dropbox" >A</div>
<div id="dropAnswr2" class="dropbox" >B</div>
<div id="dropAnswr3" class="dropbox" >C</div>
<div id="dropAnswr4" class="dropbox" >D</div>
```

You can add draggable event to elements by select their class and set call back to the drop function

```
// js
$( "#dragAnwr" ).draggable({ 
    revert: "invalid",
    cursor: 'move',
    containment: "parent" 
});

$( ".dropbox" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        // remove flag class
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
        // add class to the dropped element
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    },
    hoverClass: "drop-hover"
});
```

And some CSS for more info

```
// css
div {
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:5px;
}
.selected {
   color: red;
}
```

Hope this help! You can take a look at its fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DKUg9/5/